# Ubuntu Server 15.04 - What is the default configuration for CouchDB?

Tags: server, 15.04, couchdb

I installed the CouchDB using `aptitude install couchdb`. The service is running. I did not changed anything else. But when I try `http://127.0.0.1:5984` it gives a refused connection. Can anyone help me with my case? Thanks.

```
plntu
Ligações de Internet Activas (só servidores)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               ESCUTA      3011/smbd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3050            0.0.0.0:*               ESCUTA      1037/fbserver   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               ESCUTA      3011/smbd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211         0.0.0.0:*               ESCUTA      951/memcached   
tcp        0      0 192.168.179.11:53       0.0.0.0:*               ESCUTA      1009/named      
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               ESCUTA      2509/dnsmasq    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               ESCUTA      1009/named      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               ESCUTA      855/cupsd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               ESCUTA      1009/named      
tcp6       0      0 :::444                  :::*                    ESCUTA      2962/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    ESCUTA      3011/smbd       
tcp6       0      0 :::3689                 :::*                    ESCUTA      7146/rhythmbox  
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    ESCUTA      3011/smbd       
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    ESCUTA      2962/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    ESCUTA      1009/named      
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    ESCUTA      855/cupsd       
tcp6       0      0 ::1:953                 :::*                    ESCUTA      1009/named      
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    ESCUTA      2962/apache2    
udp        0      0 192.168.179.255:137     0.0.0.0:*                           2992/nmbd       
udp        0      0 192.168.179.11:137      0.0.0.0:*                           2992/nmbd       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:137             0.0.0.0:*                           2992/nmbd       
udp        0      0 192.168.179.255:138     0.0.0.0:*                           2992/nmbd       
udp        0      0 192.168.179.11:138      0.0.0.0:*                           2992/nmbd       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:138             0.0.0.0:*                           2992/nmbd       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           9583/libpepflashpla
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           835/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:39682           0.0.0.0:*                           835/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211         0.0.0.0:*                           951/memcached   
udp        0      0 192.168.179.11:53       0.0.0.0:*                           1009/named      
udp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           2509/dnsmasq    
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           1009/named      
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           979/cups-browsed
udp        0      0 192.168.179.11:123      0.0.0.0:*                           3067/ntpd       
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*                           3067/ntpd       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                           3067/ntpd       
udp6       0      0 :::42115                :::*                                835/avahi-daemon: r
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                835/avahi-daemon: r
udp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                                1009/named      
udp6       0      0 fe80::21c:c0ff:fe8d:123 :::*                                3067/ntpd       
udp6       0      0 ::1:123                 :::*                                3067/ntpd       
udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*                                3067/ntpd
```

If i execute couchdb it works:

```
   Apache CouchDB 1.6.0 (LogLevel=info) is starting.
    Apache CouchDB has started. Time to relax.
    [info] [<0.32.0>] Apache CouchDB has started on        http://127.0.0.1:5984/
```

And can see the `/var/log/couchdb/couchdb.log`

But this:

```
/etc/init.d/couchdb status
● couchdb.service - LSB: Apache CouchDB init script
  Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/couchdb)
   Active: active (exited) since Dom 2015-07-12 15:41:20 WEST; 11min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

Jul 12 15:41:20 hiro systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache CouchDB init script...
Jul 12 15:41:20 hiro couchdb[12366]: * Starting database server couchdb
Jul 12 15:41:20 hiro couchdb[12366]: ...done.
Jul 12 15:41:20 hiro systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache CouchDB init script.
```

Appears not working well. And appears a log which i cannot find it's location.

Additionally, the `/etc/init.d/couchdb` script has this:

```
DESCRIPTION="database server"
NAME=couchdb
SCRIPT_NAME=`basename $0`
COUCHDB=/usr/bin/couchdb
CONFIGURATION_FILE=/etc/default/couchdb
RUN_DIR=/var/run/couchdb
LSB_LIBRARY=/lib/lsb/init-functions
```

The `CONFIGURATION_FILE` points to a no existent file. I tried to change it to `/etc/couchdb/default.ini` (which is used when i execute couchdb in the terminal) but does not solve the problem.

If i run the couchdb in terminal and open a second terminal and i run `netstat -plintu` it appears:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5984          0.0.0.0:*               ESCUTA      21784/beam.smp
```

Comment: Are you running the server on your local machine or is it a remote server?

Comment: I tried with with ubuntu server 15.04 and ubuntu desktop 15.10. Same results.

Comment: Can you paste the output of `netstat -plntu`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed in a new web server and this time, the problems disappeared. I do not know what was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

to fix this problem ,I edit currently using configuration file suche as default.ini or local.ini by adding the following lines:

```
[httpd] 
enable_cors=true;  
[cors]
origins=*
```

you shoud figure out the specific domain by avoding using of * for the sake of security.for examle:

```
origins= http://yourdomain:port/
```

For more information,please ref:[couchdb configuration reference](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/config/http.html)
wish this is helpful:)